# Scroll Issue - Blackberry WebWorks

Tags: html, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I have a simple fixed size list created with `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. I can test only on my Bold 9700, but on that device it cannot scroll the list.  What is the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>
      <div class="content" style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;">
                <ul x-blackberry-focusable="true">
                     <li x-blackberry-focusable="true"> ....</li>
                     <li x-blackberry-focusable="true"> ....</li>
                     <li x-blackberry-focusable="true"> ....</li>
                     <li x-blackberry-focusable="true"> ....</li>
                     <li x-blackberry-focusable="true"> ....</li>
                     <li x-blackberry-focusable="true"> ....</li>
                     <li x-blackberry-focusable="true"> ....</li>
                     <li x-blackberry-focusable="true"> ....</li>
                     <li x-blackberry-focusable="true"> ....</li>
                </ul>
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in Blackberry Forums: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Scroll-issue-on-lists/td-p/1389871